# Sublime Build System run F5 on browser window, possible?

Tags: javascript, html, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using Sublime to edit some HTML (as some other people here and there, I guess). So the process is:

- Edit HTML and save file
- Move to the browser and hit F5 to see updated content

Is it possible to automate this via Sublime Build System?

Or, is there a more intelligent way of doing that?

Note: The file I'm editing is being served by a web server (nginx) located in another machine. So I don't want just to open file in browser locally, which seems to be the focus of another question.

Comment: Check http://gcollazo.github.io/BrowserRefresh-Sublime/

Comment: If you want a answer to the question about whether it is possible to create a build system for this, then the answer is yes. I flagged this question as a duplicate of another question that has a solution to that effect. In fact I am using the method described in the accepted answer. Hope this helps.